Loading code dynamically into compiled Android app
I have the following compiled smali code inside a non-static function:
iget-object v0, p0, Lvd/b;->a:Lbz/x;

invoke-interface {v0, p1}, Lbz/x;->func(Ljava/lang/String;)Lec/b;

move-result-object p1

I want to load this part of the code dynamically, I don't have the java source.
In Java I would use Java Runtime Compiler to get what I want, for example:
String className = "mypackage.MyClass";
String javaCode = "package mypackage;\n" +
                 "public class MyClass implements Runnable {\n" +
                 "    public void run() {\n" +
                 "        System.out.println(\"Hello World\");\n" +
                 "    }\n" +
                 "}\n";
Class<?> aClass = CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER.loadFromJava(className, javaCode);
Runnable runner = (Runnable) aClass.newInstance();
runner.run();

How can I do the same or use different kind of solution to a compiled Android code?
Thanks.

Use apktool to decompile the apk, them modify the smali code injecting your code and recompile + resign the app.

@Robert Thanks, However that's not what I meant - I want load code dynamically

Then complete the Smali code to a method and a class, "compile" it using Google smali lib and load the created DEX file using DexClassLoader.
